# The first 2 times I run the write function it creates a new line, but the third time it doesn't

Tags: rust

How can I make each string print on their own line while still forcing the user to press enter in between each String?

```
use std::io::{stdin, stdout, Read, Write};

fn write(text: &str) {
    let mut out = stdout();
    out.write_all(text.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    out.flush().unwrap();
    let _ = stdin().read(&mut [0]).unwrap();
}

fn main() {
    write("First time");
    write("Second time");
    write("Third time");
}
```

Output:

```
First time

Second timeThird time
```

Comment: I don't [see any newlines](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ea71adc27be9c91a0ad171b5e471cf75) as expected since you don't write any.

Comment: You don't print a newline, why do you expect it to print a newline?

Comment: The linefeed between `First` and `Second` is caused by the user pressing `Enter`. It is _not_ output by your program.

Comment: @TheFrog are you running this in a windows console or something? In a regular unix term it works fine for me, when the user just presses return. However because you're reading just one byte at a time from the stdin, if the user has enqueued multiple bytes (e.g. `\r\n`) before validating the leftover bytes will be used to validate the followup lines.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out it pressing enter used made 2 characters. The overflow character triggered the next line. Below code solved it for me.

```
fn write(text: &str) {
    let mut out = stdout();
    out.write_all(text.as_bytes()).unwrap();
    out.flush().unwrap();
    let _ = stdin().read(&mut [0; 10]).unwrap();
}
```